# Connecting a bot to Microsoft Teams with dedicated API?

Tags: bots, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am using a bot building w/o Microsoft bot framework. I need to connect it to the Microsoft Teams chat plateform but i can't find any API or information to done it without the Microsoft Framework.. is it at least possible ?

Have you any informations, opensource code or whatever to help me ?

Thanks,
Michael.

[EDIT] i finaly got the information directly from microsoft employer and there isnt any other way than the bot framework.. looks like apple style ahah

Answer (score 1):

This is the official documentation for the Microsoft Bot Framework for their Office365 Products, which includes Teams.

https://dev.botframework.com/

I am still having some problems myself understanding what I need to do in order to make Teams work with other languages and register my bot.